# How to insert a for loop in a try assert block (or an assert block into a loop) to avoid repeating asserts?

Tags: python, for-loop, testing, refactoring, assert

I'd like to avoid repeating an assert statement one time for each of these and more cases:

```
na000 ='567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
na003 = '45678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678'
na099 = '012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345'
na098 = '67890123456789012345678901234567890XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
na050 = '12XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
na002 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Speficaclly I'd like to avoid repeating asserts like this:

```
try:
    assert levenshteinize(na000, nai03, 1)[0] == 4, 'testing 3 substitut and 1 insert error' 
    assert levenshteinize(na000, no099, 1)[0] == 99, 'testing 99 omisions error'
    assert levenshteinize(na000, no098, sil)[0] == 98, 'testing 98 omisions error'
    assert levenshteinize(na000, no050, sil)[0] == 50, 'testing 50 omisions error'
    assert levenshteinize(na000, no002, sil)[0] == 2, 'testing 2 omisions error'
except AssertionError as e
...
```

I've inserted the strings in a dictionary with the key as the var name (the number). But what's important is that to avoid the asserts I've created a function that includes the `try... assert... except` in a `for-loop`. I've tried different versions, similar to the one below, but none of them seem to be ok (invalid syntax error detected before running it). 
EDIT: i was just missing a simple `def`. Pondering whether to delete the question now...

```
def test_lev(nerrors = defaultlist, silent = 0, levreturn: int = 0):

try:
    for num in nerrors: 
        assert nnocrate.levenshteinize(na['000'], na[numto3st(num)], silent)[levreturn] == num, f'testing {num} error'
except AssertionError as e:
    print(f'levenshtein() has failed with na when {e.args[0]}\n')
else:
    print('\nAll na assert OK')
```

How can I do that? How can I insert a for loop or something to avoid repeating the assert ?

Comment: You are missing one `'` on the last line, ie, `print('\nAll na assert OK)`. Probably that could be the reason for `SyntaxError`

Comment: Thanks Abdul, the ` ' `  is present in the original code. I just simplified that line as it was longer (but that one is ok, I'm changing it now here). But does your question imply that the for loop is ok there?

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't use the `def`  ...!  Testing now if it was just that...

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, the for line was all right. I just missed the def in the fuction... sigh... Shall i delete this question?